# how do I use tkinter's askopenfilename() and pass the file name to another function/method?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

how would i pass the img which is image upload to a vehicle detection function

```
class show_image:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.geometry('1500x1000')
        self.window.title('Image Viewer')
        self.lbl = Label(window)
        self.lbl.pack()

        frame = Frame(window)
        frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, padx=15, pady=15)

        btn = Button(frame, text="Select Image", command=self.showimage)
        btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        btn2 = Button(frame, text="Exit", command=self.backtovehiclecount)
        btn2.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=12)

    def showimage(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Select Image File", filetypes=(
            ("JPG File", "*.jpg"), ("PNG File", "*.png"), ("All file", "how are you .txt")))
        img = Image.open(filename)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.lbl.configure(image=img)
        self.lbl.image = img

    def backtovehiclecount(self):
        win = Toplevel()
        Thesis.VehicleCounting.Vehicle_Counting(win)
        self.window.withdraw()
```

This is the class with the image counting function how would i pass it on img=cv2.imread so that the image will change every time i upload a picture

```
class Vehicle_Counting:

    def __init__(self, window):

        self.window = window
        self.window.geometry('1366x768')
        self.window.resizable(0, 0)
        self.window.title('Vehicle Counting')
    def Counter(self):
        vd = VehicleDetector()
        img = cv2.imread("images/conorashleig-who-2018-thailand-phc-highres-9.jpg")
        vehicle_boxes = vd.detect_vehicles(img)
        self.vehicle_count = len(vehicle_boxes)
        for box in vehicle_boxes:
            x, y, w, h = box
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (25, 0, 180), 3)
            cv2.putText(img, "Vehicles:" + str(self.vehicle_count), (20, 50), 0, 2, (100, 200, 0), 

        cv2.imshow("Cars", img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: that's not called "*upload*". this is a "file open dialog", and your program intends to open and read a file. -- *uploading* is file transfer to a *server* on a network. this here is just a tkinter GUI.

Comment: any tips on how i can file transer transfer to a server on a network?

Comment: that's not your question though, why would you need to know that?

Comment: i just need it for my thesis need to create a button for uploading image and i can choose what image to count for vehicle

Comment: You can pass the image as an argument of `Counter()` function.

Comment: can you write it in code sir?